# Как доработать бота для Крестики-нолики на python kivy?

Tags: python, kivy, искусственный-интеллект

Выдает случайную координату, но не понимает где символ уже стоит.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.uix.label import Label
import random

Config.set("graphics","resizable","0")
Config.set("graphics","width","400")
Config.set("graphics","height","400")

choice = ['X','X']

class GameApp(App):
    def tic_tac(self,arg):
        global switch
        arg.disabled = True
        arg.text = "X"

        coordinate = (
            (0,1,2),(3,4,5),(6,7,8),
            (0,3,6),(1,4,7),(2,5,8),
            (0,4,8),(2,4,6))

        vector = (
            [self.button[x].text for x in (0,1,2)],
            [self.button[x].text for x in (3,4,5)],
            [self.button[x].text for x in (6,7,8)],

            [self.button[y].text for y in (0,3,6)],
            [self.button[y].text for y in (1,4,7)],
            [self.button[y].text for y in (2,5,8)],

            [self.button[d].text for d in (0,4,8)],
            [self.button[d].text for d in (2,4,6)])

        win = False
        color = [.20,.64,.81,1]

        for index in range(8): 
            if vector[index].count('X') == 3:
                win =True
                self.a.text = str(int(self.a.text)+1)
                for i in coordinate[index]:
                    self.button[i].color = color
                break
            elif vector[index].count('O') == 3:
                win = True
                self.b.text = str(int(self.b.text)+1)
                for i in coordinate[index]:
                    self.button[i].color = color
                break 

        ran = random.randint(0,8)
        self.button[ran].text = "O"
        self.button[ran].disabled = True


        if win:
            for index in range(9):
                self.button[index].disabled = True


    def restart(self,arg):
        global switch; switch = 0
        for index in range(9):
            self.button[index].color = [.45,.46,.42,1]
            self.button[index].text =""
            self.button[index].disabled = False
    def new_game(self,arg):
        self.a.text = "0"
        self.b.text = "0"
        global switch; switch = 0
        for index in range(9):
            self.button[index].color = [.45,.46,.42,1]
            self.button[index].text =""
            self.button[index].disabled = False


    def build(self):
        self.title = "X - O"

        root = BoxLayout(orientation = 'vertical', padding = 7)
        grid = GridLayout(cols = 3)
        self.button = [0 for _ in range(9)]
        for index in range(9):
            self.button[index] = Button(color = [.45,.46,.42,1], font_size = 35 ,disabled = False,on_press = self.tic_tac)
            grid.add_widget(self.button[index]) 

        lbls = BoxLayout(orientation = "horizontal", size_hint = (1,.11))
        self.a = Label(text = "0", size_hint = (1,.2), font_size = 27)
        self.b = Label(text = "0", size_hint = (1,.2), font_size = 27)
        lbls.add_widget(self.a)
        lbls.add_widget(self.b) 

        root.add_widget(grid)
        root.add_widget(Button(text = "Restart", size_hint = [1,.1],  on_press = self.restart))
        root.add_widget(Button(text = "New game",size_hint = [1,.1], on_press = self.new_game))
        root.add_widget(lbls)
        return root

if __name__ == "__main__" :
    GameApp().run()
```

Comment: Я не смотрел ваш код, но есть идея. Занятые ячейки вычёркивать из списка доступных ячеек, таким образом бот не будет попадать на уже занятые ячейки.

Comment: Я пытался по следующему алгоритму:если в ячейке занято, то к случайного числа (ran) добавляется единичка.Результат тот же.

Comment: А что типа единичка изменяет? Вот список: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]. Случайно выбираете из него число. Это же число удаляете из этого списка. Ваш ход - тоже удаляется из списка. Все доступные варианты остаются без чисел, которые выбрал бот и вы. Каждое число это определенная ячейка. Вообще не вижу проблем в этом плане. А если добавить направления диагоналей, вертикалей и горизонталей, то боту не всегда придется выбирать случайные ячейки.